# d Oracle connection couldnot open error from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have installed oracle express 10 on my localmachine in which all oracle client tools were already installed to connect to a remote oracle server before.After replicating the databses from remote server in the local when I try to connect to the local version or remote version from asp.net it throws an exception telling connection couldnot open.I can use the same connection parameters and connect in SQLdeveloper/toad.When I uninstall oracle express I can connect to remote server again.I am running windows xp 64 bit version.Can someone help me with this?

Comment: show the error message here so folks can help

Comment: sorry..I got the fix..installing oracleXE after installing oracle client was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..installing oracleXE after installing oracle client was the problem.The real issue was in the order of the paths variable